# Save OpenCV Image with Timestamp in Image Header? (C++)

Tags: c++, image, opencv, metadata

I'm saving a JPG image using OpenCV's [`imwrite`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gabbc7ef1aa2edfaa87772f1202d67e0ce) function in C++.

I was wondering whether it would be possible for me also edit the metadata timestamp of the JPG image I'm saving, prior to saving it, that would get saved inside the JPG file.

Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: not with opencv itself, to my knowledge. you'll have to patch that in after the fact. imagemagick can probably help.